# Modal analysis with aerodynamic damping

Tags: aerodynamics, vibrations

I'm using modal decomposition to predict the steady state response of a beam structure to harmonic loading. The structure itself is very lightly damped, but we know from experiments that the aerodynamic drag force as it moves through the air is very significant.

I have the mass and stiffness matrices for the beam ($\boldsymbol{[M]}$ and $\boldsymbol{[K]}$) and so I am able to obtain the eigenvectors and eigenvalues ($\boldsymbol{[V]}$ and $\boldsymbol{[D]}$). The eigenvalues yields a vector containing the natural frequencies of the system (the square root of the diagonal entries of $\boldsymbol{[D]}$, I'll call it $\boldsymbol{\omega}$.

The system is excited by a force vector in the global reference frame $\boldsymbol{F_0}$ at an excitation frequency $\omega_F$.

There is a rotation matrix which rotates the beams from the local to the global reference frame $\boldsymbol{[R]}$.

I have successfully used the procedure to calculate the steady state response without aerodynamic damping:

- Get eigenvalues and eigenvectors $\boldsymbol{[V]}$ and $\boldsymbol{[D]}$
- Get generalised force vector $\boldsymbol{Q}=\boldsymbol{[V]}^T \boldsymbol{F_0}$
- Calculate modal participation factor vector $\boldsymbol{q}$. The individual elements are calculated as follows:

$$q_i=\frac{Q_i}{{\omega_i}^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{[(1-(\omega_F/\omega_i)^2)^2+(2\zeta_i\omega_F/\omega_i)^2]}}$$

- Calculate response from $\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{[V]q}$

Of course, this drastically overpredicts the amplitude of the oscillations because there is no aerodynamic damping. I've found a few examples for single d.o.f. systems in which the energy lost from the system is calculated (by integrating the drag force x the velocity). The integration results in the following equation for energy loss:
$$\Delta E=\frac{8}{3}\frac{1}{2}\rho A C_D \omega^2 X^3$$
This can then be converted to an equivalent damping coefficient as follows:
$$C_{eq}=\frac{\Delta E}{\pi \omega X^2}$$
Which can be converted to a damping coefficient by doing:
$$\zeta=\frac{C_{eq}}{2 \omega_n}$$
I've modelled a simple spring-mass system with air resistance and it works fine (I have to iterate to find the final position because the amplitude calculation requires knowledge of the damping which requires knowledge of the amplitude so there is a circular reference, but that's no biggy!)

Could someone please explain the equivalent for a multi-d.o.f. system? My initial forays have been unsuccessful, with much higher drag coefficients than would really occur.

Comment: Interesting question, but one question: are you trying to write your own FEM solver for air-damped mechanical vibrations? Do commercial FEM solvers like COMSOL allow the feature of including aerodynamic damping to vibrations? When you tried applying the single DOF method to the multiple DOF problem, are you taking into account the fact that air resistance will only affect the elements which are at the surface of the structure, since the interior elements are not in contact with the air? I'd guess that if you didn't, you might get an unrealistically large drag coefficient.

Comment: Yes... I'm writing it myself. I need it to be very lightweight and be deployable on any windows machine. The structure is made of beam elements (think an electricity pylon) so your second point isn't an issue.

Comment: So $\Delta E=\frac{4}{3}\rho A C_D \omega^2 X^3$ is obtained by integrating the drag equation times velocity over one full harmonic mode cycle. But that's just for a single beam, so I'm guessing you have to compute $\Delta E$ for each individual beam (based on the magnitude of its perpendicular displacement from the beam axis) and add them up to obtain the energy loss for the entire structure over a full cycle. Then, use that to determine an overall damping coefficient for the entire structure, and then do the iteration (because of the circular reference) to determine the overall amplitude.

Comment: Another complication I just remembered: the response of the system to a sinusoidal forcing results in each eigenmode having a different phase shift depending on their frequency in comparison to the forcing frequency, with the phase shift being $\phi=\text{ArcTan}[\omega_i^2-\omega_F^2,-2\zeta\omega_F]$, so doesn't that mean that the response $\mathbf{x}=[\mathbf{V}]\mathbf{q}$ is an approximation? The amplitudes should be right, but the different modes ought to have phase shifts relative to one another.  Hmm, I'll have to look more closely tomorrow.

Comment: That's correct, however we're trying to predict the response when the structure is excited at its first natural frequency so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Do you have a reference or PDF which explains how the coordinate system works, ie what the entries of each column of $\mathbf{V}$ mean? Is $\mathbf{v}$ a $3N\times 3N$ matrix, where $N$ is the number of beam elements? Is $\mathbf{R}$ also $3N\times 3N$? I don't have an engineering background, so I'm not familiar with the coordinate system.

Comment: $\boldsymbol{[V]}$ is a matrix, the columns of which contain the orthonormalised mode shapes for the structure. It is $6N * 6N$, as the structure is 3 dimensional. Each node has 3 translational and 3 rotational degrees of freedom. $\boldsymbol{[R]} is the same size. I'll try and track down a .pdf but unfortunately the book I got it from isn't on Google books.